# Can I use node.childNodes in the if clause?

Tags: javascript

can I do

```
if (node.childNodes) {
  // do something
}
```

instead of

```
if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
  // do something
}
```

I tried it, and it works. I tried `!div.childNodes` on a div element with stuff inside it and this returned the boolean `false`. It looks like it's working, but are there any traps that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes

Comment: did you mean `!!div.childNodes` to get boolean `true` ?

Comment: although it would return true for empty list anyway

Comment: @xmike No, I did that to test if a boolean operation is possible on a node list. What I want to do is to use this boolean in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 3):

No, but:

```
 if (node.childNodes.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put virtually anything in if clause as conditional, javascript will try to coerce it to a boolean value. Everything in if clause will be coerced to a truthy value except the followings:

1. `false`
2. `null`
3. `undefined`
4. `''`
5. `NaN`

Anything else even `[]`, `{}` will be coerced to a truthy value.